# Microsoft Graph API file permissions are not visible/delete

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create Read permissions for a single file in the sharepoint online site document library without any issues.
I am capturing the permissionID while creating the permission on the specific file. immediately I am trying to delete the same permission and I am getting the below exception:

HTTP Response Code:404; Response Message: The resource could not be found

Below URL I am using to delete a permission:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root:/{pathToFile}:/permissions/{permissionID}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7BdriveId%7D/root:/%7BpathToFile%7D:/permissions/%7BpermissionID%7D).

any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @Shiva, How much delay do I need to maintain. As I am using the Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Rather using delay(since it depends on the network and infrastructure), you can try first adding the permission and later use GET call to check if your permission was added or not and then Delete it.

Comment: @Shiva,Thank you I will try that and will share you the results back.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I tried to read the created permission using the Get call. When I am trying to read using the Get Permissions call it throwing "Resource Not Found" exception.

Comment: Yes, that means the permission is not created yet. So you need to use a for loop and until you get a successful response you need to loop through and then get that deleted.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, but in the document library I could see that the file is being updated with latest permissions shared and also I am getting the invitation as well while performing the create persmission.

Comment: Can you please share the requestid and timestamp for the one that you got invitation and later getting Resource not found while getting the permission with permission id?

Comment: We need the requestid and timestamp only to check the logs, we can't do anything with permissionid. Please provide requestid and timestamp present in headers.

Comment: @Shive, the details are
Permission Create request (RequestID: c5dd6ebf-8b3e-4d8b-9861-16699f5956a0, timestamp: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 10:00:15 GMT) -- Successful
Resource Not Found (RequestID: 763d7e9d-ada1-419f-8bdb-13beaebe37a2, timestamp: Wed, 11 Nov 2020 10:02:20 GMT) -- Failure

Comment: Looks like you are not routing properly. Use the Itemid and call this way `/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{driveid}/Items/{itemid}/permissions/{Permissionid}` It worked for me.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, I have used the below API call retrieved from the documentation of Graph API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

/drives/{drive-id}/root:{/path/to/item}/permissions/{perm-id}

Comment: @Shiva, I even tried as you suggested it also giving me the same exception.
RequestId: 1e060f3b-f8d5-4278-bce1-2d8ad15c327e
URLs I tried:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/permissions/{permissionId}
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/permissions/{permissionId}

Comment: Please give a last try in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) and see if it makes a difference.